# Spliting short number to long number in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i want to split number from short to long in `textbox`.
when i put number like this `236.23.6329.5` in `textbox1`, the number convert to this `23623006329005`.
e.g

```
236.23.6329.5   to 23623006329005
369.2.326.6     to 36902000369006
123.23.365236.0 to 12323365236000
256.36.36598.4  to 25636036598004
```

i use this code   /Coded By "عبدالله بقشير" Officena.net

```
Dim sp
Dim iNum As String
Dim i As Integer
For Each sp In Split(Me.Textbox1, ".")
    i = i + 1
    iNum = iNum & Format(sp, IIf(i = 3, "0000", "000"))
    Next
Me.Textbox1= iNum
```

but this convert from 362.36.236 to 3620360236 if the number contain Two "."

Comment: When you added your code, it contradicts your requirement. So what is your final req? 3.3.4.3 or 3.2.6.3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim mylen, mynum, x, mylong
Dim i As Integer

mylen = Array(3,2,6,3)
mynum = Split(Textbox1,".")

For i = Lbound(mynum) to Ubound(mynum)
    x = mynum(i)
    Do While Len(x) < mylen(i)
        x = "0" & x
    Loop
    mylong = mylong & x
Next
```

I declared most of the variable as variant.
You can improve it by declaring it directly as array with its corresponding data type.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i have this code

        Dim sp
    Dim iNum As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each sp In Split(Me.Textbox1, ".")
        i = i + 1
        iNum = iNum & Format(sp, IIf(i = 3, "000", "000"))
        Next
    Me.Textbox1= iNum

but convert Number from 632.2.36 to 632002036 if input text contain Two "." in textbox
i want to convert number  from 
236.23.6329.5   to 23623006329005
369.2.326.6     to 36902000369006
123.23.365236.0 to 12323365236000
256.36.36598.4  to 25636036598004
the number contain Three "."

Comment: Hmmm, so is it always the last dot `.` that is missing?

Comment: Thanks for try help but can you see my Questions again

Comment: Then just force the input to have 3 dots? That's easier :) that way no need to guess which part was omitted.